# Scraping only 3 items from the site

Tags: java, for-loop, jsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** only 3 names of the book from the HTML site using `Jsoup`.

By this way it **scrapes** me whole site. I just want to **scrape** 3, I tried with different kinds of for loop and different combinations but it didn't go very well

```
for (Element row : doc.select("div.productWrapper")) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName(row.select("div.productWrapper").select("a").attr("title"));
        empikBestsellers.add(book);
   }
```

Edit:

Is this the best way to do it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setName(doc.select("div.productWrapper").get(i).select("a").first().attr("title"));
            empikBestsellers.add(book);
        }
```

Comment: If you only want some of the items in div.productWrapper, you need to write a more specific selector, or hardcode the loop to stop after 3 rows

Comment: Here is the site: https://www.empik.com/bestsellery/ksiazki I want just first 3

Comment: @dementis could you show how it would looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Elements`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) inherits from [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), so you can access individual elements directly.

You can then either use a regular [`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop to stop after some number of elements, or you can just get the elements one at a time without a loop.

Comment: Put the call to `doc.select` outside the loop (assign it to a variable)—as it is now, you are searching the whole page three times instead of searching it once and getting the three results you need. Other than that, try running it to see if it works. It looks to me like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the entire collection, just loop through for 3 times. Something like...

```
List<Element> elements = doc.select("div.productWrapper");
//Holds number of times to loop
int numLoops = 3;

//Check to make sure there's enough of the desired number of elements
if(elements.size() < numLoops) {
  numLoops = elements.size();
}

//Loop for desired number of times
for (int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++) {
  Element row = elements.get(i);
  Book book = new Book();
  book.setName(row.select("div.productWrapper").select("a").attr("title"));
  empikBestsellers.add(book);
}
```